# Extracting the call of a model with formula object as input

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am wondering how to extract the call of a (linear) model in case a formula object is used as input.

For example, the following returns the call:

```r
getCall(lm(mpg ~ am + cyl, data = mtcars))
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ am + cyl, data = mtcars)
```

However, when I use a formula object then the extracted call returns the name of the object. Is it possible to return the formula itself?

```r
fm <- formula(mpg ~ am + cyl)
getCall(lm(fm, data = mtcars))
#> lm(formula = fm, data = mtcars)
```

I would like to have the following:

```r
fm <- formula(mpg ~ am + cyl)
getCall(lm(fm, data = mtcars))
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ am + cyl, data = mtcars)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: `m = do.call("lm", list(formula=fm, data=quote(mtcars)))`